# Python: Possible to make attribute access strictly private?

Tags: python, ironpython

If I have a class that contains a dictionary that I need to reuse among various instance methods, but I want to make that dictionary only writable from a specific instance method, is that possible?

In this code:

```
class GoodClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # name mangling enabled!
        self.__dict = {}

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict)

    def add_to_dict(self, key, item):
        # this should be the only method that can write to self.__dict
        try:
            self.__dict[key] += [item]
        except KeyError:
            self.__dict[key] = [item]

    def make_items(self, n_items=3, important_param=1):
        # do the important stuff
        for i in range(n_items):
            item = "param: {}".format(important_param)

            self.add_to_dict("important_items", item)

    def this_is_bad(self):
        # don't want this to be possible
        self.__dict["this is bad"] = ["quite bad"]

c = GoodClass()

c.make_items()
c.this_is_bad()

# c.__dict["can't do this"] = ["thanks mangling!"]

print(c)
# {'important_items': ['param: 1', 'param: 1', 'param: 1'], 'this is bad': ['quite bad']}
```

Is there a way to ensure that `add_to_dict` is the only method that can write to the dictionary in the same way that mangling prevents writing to it from outside the class?

My use case is in a hosted version of IronPython, so `inspect.currentframe` doesn't work as mentioned in a couple answers below. Though, that should work for unhosted IronPython or other versions.

Comment: ...why? Even in languages with a `private` specifier, I can't think of any that have a feature like this.

Comment: Particularly, if you want other methods to be able to *read* `self.__dict`, and you want `__init__` to be able to *initialize* `self.__dict`, but you only want one specific method to be able to *add items to* `self.__dict`, that's just not how Python's object model works.

Comment: Hypothetically, you could probably do this with the `__setattr__` magic method, but @user2357112 is right and my response would be.... why?

Comment: public reading isn't an issue, there can just a be a `GoodClass.dict` property. the idea is to prevent another method directly overwriting `self.__dict["important_items"]`

Comment: You could rename `self.__dict` to `self._only_write_from_add_to_dict_method` (both easy to implement and obvious to users of the class).

Comment: ...yes that is obvious, but it would be nice if the code prevented illegal actions rather than just wagging a textual finger at you...

Comment: why? we're all adults here. (and the answers listed are way too convoluted).  Perhaps what you're really looking for is `self.__dict = defaultdict(list)`? Then you would always do `self.__dict['...'].append(...)` and never `self.__dict['...'] = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have no idea why you would want to do this, I think this could work for you :

First approach :

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @property
    def some_variable(self):
        return self.__some_variable

    @some_variable.setter
    def some_variable(self, value):
        current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
        calling_function = inspect.getouterframes(current_frame, 2)[1][3]
        if (calling_function != "allowed_func_name"):
            raise Exception()
        self.__some_variable = value
```

Second approach :

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_variable_set_flag = False
        pass
    def some_func(self, value):
        self.some_variable_set_flag = True
        try :
            self.some_variable = value
        finally :
            self.some_variable_set_flag = False

    @property
    def some_variable(self):
        return self.__some_variable

    @some_variable.setter
    def some_variable(self, value):
        if (not self.some_variable_set_flag):
            raise Exception()
        self.__some_variable = value
```

- This approach wont give you complete protection but would require manual overriding.

Its in an abstract way (if anyone else would look for this some time).

Comment: That may work for someone else, though. Unfortunately, my use case is a hosted version of IronPython and `currentframe` returns `None`. That's not clear though, so I'll update my question. Thanks!

Comment: You could try a similar approach, which wont completely block it but would give you some kind of protection, ill edit. @tykom Edited.

Comment: For extra caution, use `try/finally` to ensure that `self.some_variable_set_flag = False` runs at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I think the flagging approach and `try/finally` is the cleanest. I was hoping that there was an object-level way to do this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @tykom Ill sleep on it, might think of a better approach. The main problem is not knowing the callers identity (due to the inspect None return).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can make the dict only allow setting values from the right place:

```
import inspect

class GoodDict(dict):
    __allowed_codes = {GoodClass.add_to_dict.__code__}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        while frame:
            if frame.f_code in GoodDict.__allowed_codes:
                break
            frame = frame.f_back
        else:
            raise Exception('__setitem__ called from non-allowed function')

        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

If deleting from the dict is a concern, you should also implement `__delitem__`.

Then use it in `GoodClass`: `self.__dict = GoodDict()`.

Finally you should make the values tuples instead of lists to ensure immutability.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking I may have to subclass `dict` to do it properly. Unfortunately I can't use `inspect.currentframe`.

Comment: @tykom I've just realised this can be bypassed quite easily by writing `dict.__setitem__(self.__dict, "this is bad", ["quite bad"])`. How difficult are you hoping to make it to overwrite?

Comment: ideally as hard as name mangling makes it to write to it from outside the class. but maybe that is overkill...losing the info in the dict could end up polluting several thousand images that this is creating