# @property to privatize variables in Python

Tags: python, properties, private

most threads suggest that to privatize a variable, it should be declared like `_var` or `__var` to emulate private variables as described in 
[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) that we can use `@property` to make a variable read-only. So is there a way around to alter the property's value or is it safe to assume it works well as a private variable.

Comment: Yes, there is a way around it. But there's always a way to break your code if someone is doing silly things.

Comment: “Private” and “read-only” aren’t the same thing. Which do you want?

Comment: I want “private” but as their isn’t any modifier for it . I was looking for the next best thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010964/python-possble-to-make-attribute-access-strictly-private/50011141#50011141

Comment: You really should stop worrying about other people breaking your code, they can do it in any programming language and [it's explicitly their fault](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#we-are-all-responsible-users) in python.